# How do I make the below UI completely responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

[Please take a look at this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUkVn.png)

Below is my html, currently only for 2 legs/flights but I should be able to design for upto 5 legs.

For now, I've given a percentage width to the lines in between, the rest of the elements have a fixed widths.

```
<div class="roster-steps">

                                <span class="roster-points">DOH</span>
                                <span class="roster-meta-bottom-step-one font-size-065">E17 MAR 10:30</span>
                                <span class="fa  fa-circle-thin fa-lg"></span>

                                <span class="o-arrow"><hr class="hr-custom-three"></span>

                                <span><i class="fa fa-plane roster-points" ></i></span>
                                <span class="roster-meta-step2-top font-size-065">QR 2345 A360</span>
                                <span class="roster-meta-bottom-step-two font-size-065">10:30 hrs</span>
                                <span class="roster-meta-bottom-step-twosub font-size-065"><span class="two-sub1" >OP</span><span class="two-sub2">B</span></span>

                                <span class="arrow-o"><hr class="hr-custom-three" ></span>

                                <span class="fa  fa-circle-thin fa-lg"></span>
                                <span class="roster-points">LHR</span>
                                <span class="roster-meta-bottom-step-three font-size-065"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i> E17 MAR 16:30</span>
                                <span class="roster-meta-bottom-step-threesub font-size-065"><i class="fa fa-plane fa-rotate-90"></i> E17 MAR 17:30</span>
                                <span class="fa  fa-circle-thin fa-lg"></span>

                                <span class="o-arrow"><hr class="hr-custom-three" ></span>

                                <span><i class="fa fa-taxi roster-points" ></i></span>
                                <span class="roster-meta-step4-top font-size-065">TAXI</span>
                                <span class="roster-meta-bottom-step-four font-size-065">1:30 hrs</span>
                                <span class="roster-meta-bottom-step-foursub font-size-065"><span class="four-sub1" >DH</span></span>

                                <span class="arrow-o"><hr class="hr-custom-three" ></span>

                                <span class="fa  fa-circle-thin fa-lg"></span>
                                <span class="roster-points">LGW</span>
                                <span class="roster-meta-bottom-step-one font-size-065">E17 MAR 20:00</span>

                            </div>
```

Any guidance in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Edit:

Can't make it vertical now as the design team has signed off on this.

So it was super easy doing this with css grid layout:

[Check it out](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryPzzE)

Note: To view it in chrome You need to  turn on the experimental flag.
First load the chrome://flags URL and scroll down to the option to Enable     experimental Web Platform features

**But since css grid layout is still not supported in major browsers, is there a more reliable alternative?**

Thanks.

Comment: For mobiles I would make it vertical rather than horizontal. You should show *all* of the **relevant** code that you're using so that we can see what you've tried properly, including styling.

Comment: I agree making it vertical for small devices will be good.

Comment: @AndyHolmes, I've included codepen link now for clarity and  avoided only irreleavent styles .

Answer (score 0):

You should use media queries. Something like this :

```css
@media screen and (max-width:450px){
  /**
  your css code for mobile version of website
  **/
}
```

You can learn more about responsiveness from here : [responsive website css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: I'm aware of media queries. I'm just looking for the most effecient way to make this more responisve Instead of writing media queries covering lot of breakpoints.

Comment: I don;t think there is an easier way than media queries if you want to have a completely responsive design

Comment: @user1854422 : As far as efficiency and control to each screen size is considered i think the best way is to use media queries. I take complete control of all different screen size categories by using bootstrap and backing it up with my media queries. It's simple and sophisticated.